# Fabric 1.4.2 -> 2.0 alpha System Minimum HW requirements?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are currently *trying* to deploy a POC Fabric network with 5 orgs participating across two channels, with private data on each channel, using Raft. This mirrors the HLF sample network for 4 orgs outlined in the docs.

It has been suggested on RocketChat and elsewhere that we may have a system resource issue *however* there is no, as in ZERO, info on minimum system requirements for HLF installs -- so we are asking for input based on the scenario / issues below. We are running on current macOS. Docker is dedicated to only HLF test cases so there are no other containers running -- ever.

We have run through *all* the tutorials successfully with a couple of exceptions:

-- When we spin up BYFN per HLF tutorial steps, while console (terminal) output indicates success for START and END, we see via Kitematic that two entities -- sometimes orderers, sometimes peers, sometimes one of each -- are stopped. These containers exhibit no errors. Containers for other *running* entities may have errors listed, but eventually recover.

-- Commercial Paper seems to run as per the docs. We will be testing *again* FabCar today.

So my ask: what are the minimum and suggested *system* configurations for a viable HLF POC test case, memory, available disk, etc? We are more than confident in all prerequisite software installed.

One final note -- we do not believe this is a sys sizing issue but wanted to confirm as HLF's dev team has confirmed to us that there were in-fact issues with 1.4.x and 2.0 builds mixed on github which appears *may* have been resolved.

We want to take system config off the table so we can move forward with *actual* HLF implementation issues.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance -- reviewing AWS, et al guides do not apply as we are running locally in a private network.

Comment: What issues are/were you seeing?  What issues did the Fabric dev team confirm?
Are you trying to size for some specific performance?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - we are trying to *successfully* run BYFN with Raft and as described above each time we attempt -- two services (containers) stop -- please carefully read the above -- could be a peer, orderer, ca, etc - so it was suggested that we examine our system configuration -- again this is a very simple ask -- what are *your* recommended minimum system requirements -- memory, cpu, disk, etc -- for a successful implementation of *your* tutorial examples?? This s/b a straightforward question with straightforward guidelines?

Comment: @GariSingh please see org post for details on what we are seeing -- we are trying to size for performance of *your* published tutorials, most notably BYFN, Commercial Paper and the 4 org multi-channel example - all against Raft. Period. This s/b an easy question to answer with recommended guidelines for *minimum* system config. for any user interested in using -- or investing in HLF -- for business reasons???

Comment: We have many people that are able to run the tutorial examples on a basic workstation.   I have a 2-core, 8GB Mac and using Docker for Mac I can run all of the tutorials.   But I'm not trying to do performance or scale testing.